# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am getting these errors in my rails project when i add a new product

" show.html.erb:52: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'

show.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' "

even when there a only 50 lines in my show.html.erb

MY SHOW.HTML.ERB

```
<body style="background-image:url('/images/Linux Wallpaper.jpg');">

<div class="panel panel-default panel-list" style="width:70%;margin:20px auto;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(126, 232, 173, 0.78);">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-family:lucida;display:bold;">
        <% if @product.user == current_user %>
          <p style="float: right;"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), :style=>"background-color:rgb(10, 245, 61);padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;border-radius: 6px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);"  %> </p>

          <p style="float: left;"><%= link_to 'Back', products_path, :style=>"background-color:rgb(10, 245, 61);padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;border-radius: 6px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);" %><p>
           <center>YOUR PRODUCT : <%=@product.title%></center> 
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-4" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <%= image_tag(@product.img_url.url(:large),:style => "height:400px;width:800px;border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
              <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">Name:</strong><br>
            <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
            <%= @product.title%>
                </div>
        </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">File Type:</strong><br>
            <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
            <%= @product.filetype%>
                </div>
        </div>
<div style="float:right;padding-right:10%;">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
  <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">Price:</strong><br>
        <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
  $<%= @product.price %>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;padding-right:10%;">
<div>
  <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">Tags:</strong><br>
        <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
  $<%= @product.all_tags %>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

so can anyone help with my problem plz

Answer (score 1):

Your image_tag function is never closed

```
<%= image_tag(@product.img_url.url(:large),:style => "height:400px;width:800px;border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);" %>
```